# Error Deploying VueJs App (Laravel) - ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

**I have this problem at the time of deploying Vue with Laravel.**

I have node js 12 and laravel 6 installed, everything is correct but when I start the application I get that error:

```
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/cl.domain.com/resources/js/app.js:3
global.window = window;´

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/cl.domain.com/resources/js/app.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    at Module.require (/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at loadApplication (/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:243:2)
    at setupEnvironment (/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:214:2)
```

My code:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-flash-message');
require('vue-flash-message/dist/vue-flash-message.min.css');

Vue.use(VueFlashMessage);
```

Comment: `global` does not exist in a browser, if you want to have a global `global` variable, you can do `window.global = window`. If you're in a node environement, the `window` variable does not exist.

Comment: At the same time, `window` doesn't exist in Node.